# Im trying to do sentiment analysis, need advice on how to start

Tags: python, bigdata, sentiment-analysis

I have decided to start a sentiment analysis project and am not sure exactly how to start and what to use. 
I have heard of Naive Baes classifier but im not sure how to use it in python or how it works.

If i have to find, the net sentiment i have to find, the *value* of each word. Is there an already created database full of words and sentiment or must i create a list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked at this for a couple years but...

at that time NLTK was the thing to use for natural language processing.  There were a few papers and projects, with source code, demonstrating sentiment analysis with NLTK.

I just googled and found http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/ and the page has examples, and links to others. including "Training a naive bayes classifier for sentiment analysis using movie reviews"

Comment: Do you know about any dictionary i can download and use right away?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of datasets you can use as training datasets but I'd recommend you build your own to ensure your classifier is set up properly for your domain.

For example, you could start with the [Cornell Movie Review dataset](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/) as a way to get started.  I'd be very surprised if this dataset worked for your needs but it would allow you to get started building your classification system.